# Unable to access the Jenkins application while installing Siebel on Oracle cloud infrastructure

Tags: siebel, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to complete the Oracle By Example tutorial
Deploying Siebel Application Using Docker Image on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure with Vanilla Database

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/compute-iaas/deploy_siebel_instance_OCI_VM/deploy_siebel_instance_OCI_VM.html

Currently stuck at the section number 6 - step # 1 - Generating Jenkins URL
It asks to copy the public IP of the VCIN and append :8080 to it in order to access the Jenkins application. However I have attempted this twice and unable to access it.

Any inputs would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by “unable to access it?” What errors are you seeing? Open your browser’s developer tools and look at the network requests and payload as you repro the issue. You should be able to see some error response that could give you hints on why the step is failing.

Comment: If the error response message is unclear and you are still blocked, kindly reach out to the support team at OCI. To expedite the troubleshooting process, capture your repro by providing a copy of the HAR file to the support case engineer so that your exact repro details can be forwarded to the product team for further investigation. Instructions (non-OCI official) to generate the HAR file can be found at https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting

Comment: Hi Ling Toh - Thank you for your response. Below is the error I am seeing in the network response and UI. It spins for a long time and then errors out <HEAD><TITLE>internal error - server connection terminated</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>internal error - server connection terminated</H1><HR>

Comment: Unfortunately, the message does not reveal much. Kindly contact the support team for help and provide the HAR file.